# save xml to xmlfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
XElement xml2 = new XElement("TopMenus", from b in dc.TopMenuu() select new XElement("TopMenu", new XElement("Id", b.Id), new XElement("Title", b.Title), new XElement("Parent_fk", b.Parent_FK), new XElement("PageURL", b.PageUrl)));
    xml2.Save(Server.MapPath(".") + "\\XML\\TopMenu.xml");// this line say error
```

results in an error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IranFairNew\XML\TopMenu.xml' because it is being
>   used by another process.

this error While simultaneously looking at the browser IE, and Mozilla can run my program
asp.net 3.5

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check nothing is using your file. Looks like your file is in use